# crop marks for print in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, bleed

I got really confused with this. I read a lot about this, but yet can't be sure. I'm trying to make A4 document(graphic design work, not text-only doc.) for print. The problem is I don't know who is printing this(no idea how, in what printer etc), but I got twice my document with white spaces in sides(up-down and left-right). At the first one, I didn't know about crop marks and bleed, and the file size was original: 210x197mm and 300pix/inch resolution. In the second, I add an extra space(with graphics) to the edges.

Now, I need it to be done for sure, but I'm not really sure again :( I add again extra space to edges(5mm each edge, in total 10mm sides, 10mm height) and used graphics to fulfill this extra space. Plus, I did black crop marks as was explained here([some tutorial at youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVwZPb2qz9I)) but I don't know how printer works, because the color of this crop marks is black, but at two of the sides I have a background dark as well(#5c0d0d), so I don't know if it will cut it as I want it or not(by this crop marks). I can't add an image of the work, because of the terms etc, but I did the image of the corner:

[image: Enlared left-down corner of the crop mark of the original image]

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crop marks will look like below. I cannot see any crop marks in the sample image you provided. The white rectangle is there to show the area I want to retain, the finished page size so to speak.

[image]

Comment: I actually enlarged the corner of my image. It's a down-left corner of my picture, that's why there's a line of black at the left-top and right-down corners of it. Thank you for providing such a good example, but can you tell me is there any specific measure between the white rectangle and the crop mark(I'm talking about the space between them)?

Comment: The distance from the crop mark to the area is not important as long as they do not intrude into the area. Imagine them as dots placed before bringing a ruler to connect them. That's the purpose.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I hope this time it will print as it should

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature built into Photoshop. Use the `File > Print` dialogue box and then move down to `Printing Marks` to place them on the print.

Alternatively — and I know you're going to hate this — use Illustrator or InDesign, which are more purpose-built for printed documents whereas Photoshop is intended for image creation and editing.[image]

Comment: Is this something I can save to photoshop's pdf file and it will be recognized by commercial printing machine?

Comment: This is a good idea if you have a document size, gutters, margins, all set. Otherwise you will end up guessing them in the print dialog window. They work much better as scottperezfox indicated in InDesign because it requires the page be set up whereas Photoshop is document canvas oriented. That's why I suggested doing it manually in Photoshop.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, I'll take that point on board.

Answer (score -1):

Place the image in InDesign, print to postscript, distill to pdf. 
Easy. If not, ask a professional.

Comment: Honestly, this isn't very helpful. You're describing a multi-step process which may be easy to you, but may be tough for someone else. Rubbing in his status as not-a-pro isn't constructive either.

Post a few screenshots for an alternative method — I think we'd all find it useful to see some new ways to reach the same end.